# recover deleted folders on Ubuntu server

Tags: server, data-recovery

I've deleted folder on Ubuntu server 16.4 . I did it via SFTP (using Transmit) by simply deleting them via GUI. Is there a way to recover them?

Comment: Have you checked the Rubbish Bin or did you do a shift-delete to permanently remove them?

Comment: I hit Command+Delete on MAC OS via Transmit